# Probability of a number comes before another in a permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

in a random permutation of numbers 1-100, what is the probability of number $k$ comes before numbers 20-40 (or any other set of numbers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a random permutation of the set $\{k, 20,21,\ldots,40\}$ the number $k$ has equal chances to appear at the first place as any other number. Use this approach and write answer.